# SQL Server 2008 evaluation edition

Tags: sql-server-2008

My evaluation edition expired and I do not have a licensed version. Can I uninstall and then reinstall another evaluation edition and if not will I be able to restore my databases to a SQL Server 2008 Express edition?

Comment: How about actually **buying** the software if you need it?? As a developer, you can get a developer edition for something like $50 or so...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can restore to SQL Server express but there is a size limit of 10 GB. Don't know about the reinstall of the evaluation...uninstall and reinstall and see what happens or get the [SQL  Server 2008 R2 evaluation](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/trial-software.aspx). Another option is the developer edition for about $50

Comment: what about reinstalling another sql evaluation edition on the same pc?

Comment: Just to be nitpicky: SQL Server 2008 Express has a 4 GB limit on database size - SQL Server 2008 R2 Express has 10 GB.

Comment: The evaluation edition is for just that -- *evaluation*.  If you are using it, especially to the point where you can't do without it, buy a license.

Comment: marc_s Then this page is wrong I guess http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx I guess they are using R2 info here, that is correct R2 and 2008 show the same

Comment: its not about the license right now... I need to restore my data so I can move it to server with sql server 2005 installed. I wanted to restore it to the 2008 version so I can export the data and script the schema. I see the databases but I cannot do anything with them.

Comment: Once you have a 2008 version backup or mdf/ldf file you can't restore it on a previous version (2005)